# Consumer finds no messages until I pause execution in the debugger

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using the kafka high level consumer. When I start up the consumer it finds all new messages. It finds new messages as I produce them using the Java kafka producer. However after a minute, it continues looping, but finding no new messages. When I pause execution in the debugger, the consumer suddenly starts to find messages to consume.
I'm using version 0.8.0 in Java.
Note, the process that consumes the messages, upon an error, will produce messages in a separate 'error' topic. When I stop producing these error messages, I stop getting this problem.

Comment: Please post your code for us to figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a kafka bug that I haven't seen reported.
If you use the same ConsumerConnector to create more than one ConsumerIterator (by giving it a map of more than one topic), the topics get switched in the ConsumerIterators every so often. If you attempt to look at the consumerIterator, by pausing in a debugger, they switch back.

Here's my old code for creating ConsumerIterators that has the bug:

```
/**
 * @param zookeeperAddresses (includes the port number)
 * @param topics all topics to be consumed.
 * @return A list of ConsumerIterators.
 */
public List<ConsumerIterator> getConsumers(String zookeeperAddresses, List<String> topics) {
    String groupId = "client_" + topics.get(0);
    LOGGER.info("Zookeeper address = " + zookeeperAddresses + ", group id = " + groupId);
    ConsumerConnector consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
            createConsumerConfig(zookeeperAddresses, groupId));
    consumers.add(consumer);
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String topic : topics) {
        topicCountMap.put(topic, Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<ConsumerIterator> topicConsumers = new LinkedList<>();
    for (String topic : topics) {
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
        assert(streams.size() == 1);
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerIterator = streams.get(0).iterator();
        topicConsumers.add(consumerIterator);
    }
    return topicConsumers;
}
```

Here's the fixed code that works around this bug:

```
/**
 * @param zookeeperAddresses (includes the port number)
 * @param topics all topics to be consumed.
 * @return A list of ConsumerIterators.
 */
public List<ConsumerIterator> getConsumers(String zookeeperAddresses, List<String> topics) {
    String groupId = "client_" + topics.get(0);
    LOGGER.info("Zookeeper address = " + zookeeperAddresses + ", group id = " + groupId);
    List<ConsumerIterator> topicConsumers = new LinkedList<>();
    for (String topic : topics) {
        ConsumerConnector consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
                createConsumerConfig(zookeeperAddresses, groupId));
        consumers.add(consumer);
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<>();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, Integer.valueOf(1));
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
        assert(streams.size() == 1);
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerIterator = streams.get(0).iterator();
        topicConsumers.add(consumerIterator);
    }
    return topicConsumers;
}
```